# C++ Problem with creating thread using Bind

Tags: c++, multithreading, function-pointers, bind

I have a little problem concerning thread and bind interaction.

It is simple, i have this situation

```
class myclass {
   // ...
   // ...
   void dosome();
   void doanother(myclass2, myclass3*);
   void run() {
      this->_myt = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(
         new boost::thread(boost::bind(&myclass::dosome, this)));
   }
   // ...
   boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> _myt;
   //...
};
```

OK, well till now everything is okay. I understand that bind is able to bind a function or a pointer to a function to some values, or better, some argument values.
When I call on a myclass object the function run() a new thread is started. I have a question, why does bind, in run, takes parameter this, when function dosome does not use any parameter? is it because there is always, for class functions, an implicit argument that is the pointer to the class???

OK, this is not my only problem.
Inside dosome, which is the execution flow of my first thread I do this:

```
void myclass::dosome() {
   myclass2 m;
   myclass3* x = new myclass3;
   boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread( 
      boost::bind(&myclass::doanother, m, x, this))); // Line X
}
```

Well I want to exec another thread.
First question: shared_prt is a smart pointer, this means that if dosome() gets out from its exec flow, the thread it executed from that scope will persist, being a shared_ptr... please tell me this is correct.
Second question: compiler gets really mad for the instruction at line X...
The problem is the bind, it probably does not like what I passed there... why? this is a member function (I talk about doanother) and there are two arguments plus this...
Where is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K. Use the preview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can think of it as an implicit parameter. Or you can think of this like `bind` needs to call your member function like `something->your_member()`, so you must tell it what `something` is.
2. You don't store the `shared_ptr` anywhere, in the second example, so it will be destroyed immediately after it's created. The thread object it points to will be destroyed too. However thread's execution itself is not bound to the thread object, so this will work in exactly the same way:

   ```
   void myclass::dosome() {
      myclass2 m;
      myclass3* x = new myclass3;
      boost::thread(boost::bind(&myclass::doanother, this, m, x)); // Line X
   }
   ```

   This starts a new thread and looses it, just like in your code. The thread continues to run.
3. As you see above, `this` should be passed as the second parameter to bind.

Answer (score 2):

For the boost::bind 'this' is the first parameter (or rather the first parameter of myclass::doanother is 'this'):

```
boost::bind(&myclass::doanother, this, m, x)
```

> why does bind, in run, takes parameter
>   this, when function dosome does not
>   use any parameter?

All class methods have a first parameter of 'this', we never have to type it, the compiler adds it automatically. Each instance of a class uses the same code but has it's own member variables. The 'this' parameter is a pointer to the member variables to be used by the method.

Also do you really want to be binding to this in another thread. It means multiple threads will have access to the member variables of the same instance which is doable but probably not the way I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to answer in parts..

> Well I want to exec another thread.
>   First question: shared_prt is a smart
>   pointer, this means that if dosome()
>   gets out from its exec flow, the
>   thread it executed from that scope
>   will persist, being a shared_ptr...
>   please tell me this is correct.

NO. There are no other references to this object, so when the shared_ptr goes out of scope, the thread object will be deleted, and all sorts of crap could happen...

Second, `boost::bind` takes the pointer to member function and then the object, followed by the parameters...